# API protection for on-premise product

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth-2.0

Context:

We have started exposing the functionality of an on-premise product through REST APIs.

Questions:

How do I protect REST APIs? One of the options is OAuth2 but I don't want a dependency on an OAuth2 server which, IMO, may not be available with all customers. Is HMAC signature a viable option? If yes, what are the advantages and disadvantages as compared with OAuth2?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 is the way to go to secure REST APIs. The Authorization Server can be delivered as a part of your product and deployment, it does not need to be a heavy-weight pre-existing component that is run by the customer.